# Feature has been removed

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet, runtime

We have been trying to build the node locally on a colleague's computer. The node successfully builds on my computer but fails to do so on the other computer. The error thrown is:
[image]

Both the computer's have same version of rustc, also tried building the image through docker still the same issue.